# Allocation of amount by dates and status SQL

Tags: sql, date, filter, bucket, bin

I am currently querying just from one table, but the issue is my fiscal year it goes:

```
Q1 01/30/2021 to 04/30/2021
Q2 05/01/2021 to 07/30/2021
Q3 07/31/2021 to 10/29/2021
Q4 10/30/2021 to 01/28/2021
```

Does anyone knows how could I create a column that will show the quarter based on the dates above?

Outcome:

```
Order Number  Order Date  Amount  Fiscal Year 
1              01/01/2021    5    FY21Q1
2              05/15/2021    5    FY21Q2
3              08/10/2021    10   FY21Q3
4              09/10/2020    8    FY20Q3
```

Thanks

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.